# Measure for countable non-disjoint union (but arbitrary intersections are Null-Sets)

Tags: measure-theory

I have a measure space $(X, \xi, \mu)$ and $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \xi^\mathbb{N}$ with $\mu(A_l \,\cap\,A_k) = 0$ for $l \neq k$. I do want to show:

$$\mu(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_n)$$

but seem to get stuck. I start by defining $B_n := A_n \setminus \bigcup_{m < n}A_m$ and get:

$$\mu(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) = \mu(\dot{\bigcup}\,B_n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(B_n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_n \setminus \bigcup_{m < n}A_m)$$

but fail to include the extra information $\mu(A_l \,\cap\,A_k) = 0$ for $l \neq k$ at this point. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Hint: What is the difference between measures of $A_n$ and $A_n\setminus\bigcup_{m<n}A_m$?

Comment: @Wojowu $A_n = (A_n \setminus \cup_{m<n}\,A_m) \,\dot\cup \cup_{m<n} \,(A_n \cap A_m)$. This gets us $\mu(A_n \setminus \cup_{m<n}\,A_m) = \mu(A_n) + \mu(\cup_{m<n} \,(A_n \cap A_m)) = \mu(A_n)$?